# Parsing json object from google api returning null

Tags: android, android-json

I am making a simple application where i scan the barcode of a book and fetch its title and author from Google APIs,

Now, this is the url for json(for a particular book i am scanning)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9788120305960
```

using this code to get json in a string

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection  = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
        String line = "";

        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            response+=line;
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        Log.d("Info",response);
        return response;
```

I store the result in a string and use this code to parse through
(`json_response` is a string)

```
            JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(json_response);
            JSONArray items = rootObject.getJSONArray("items");
            JSONObject items_object = items.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject volume_info = items_object.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            book.setTitle(volume_info.getString("title"));
            JSONArray authors = volume_info.getJSONArray("authors");
            Log.d("Info","authors array length: "+authors.length());
            String author="";
            for (int i =0;i<authors.length();i++)
            {
                author+=authors.getString(i)+", ";
            }

            book.setAuthor(author);
```

The exception is:

```
Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

also I used logcat to see what is contained in `json_response` it looks something like this

```
null{ "kind": "books#volumes", "totalItems": 1, "items":...
```

The `null` here is probably causing the problem, so... any insights how to deal with this???

PS: I am a student , dealing first time with json and android, code is unprofessional, please pardon :)

Comment: You should initialise the variable `response` to empty string. Does it help?

Comment: You can use the [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) to get a response from the google. After that use the [GSON](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library) that will ease your work while parsing the JSON.

Comment: Yep it worked by setting response to empty string!!

Comment: ok I will add it as answer. Please accept it if you found useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

```
null{ "kind": "books#volumes", "totalItems": 1, "items":...
```

means that the `response` value has not been initialised.

You should therefore initialise it to empty string.